# Use listener container for heartbeats in spring kafka

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I'm trying to set up container to listen to heartbeat topic - I'm only interested when the listener container is idle - Is it possible to configure the container without @KafkaListener and with only EventListener to listen to idle event ? Is it possible to set up seek in the idle event listener to get the last message from the topic for context information  like time and other details ?

Is there a event to know the consumer has starting consuming after the idle event without needing to use @KafkaListener ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no event that consumption has restarted.

It's not clear what you mean by "without needing to use `@KafkaListener`"; you can create your own listener...

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class So63957429Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(So63957429Application.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer<String, String> container(
            ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> factory, MyListener myListener) {

        ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer<String, String> container = factory.createContainer("so63957429");
        container.getContainerProperties().setMessageListener(myListener);
        return container;
    }

    @Bean
    public NewTopic topic() {
        return TopicBuilder.name("so63957429").partitions(1).replicas(1).build();
    }


    @Bean
    public ApplicationRunner runner(KafkaTemplate<String, String> template) {
        return args -> template.send("so63957429", "foo");
    }

}

@Component
class MyListener extends AbstractConsumerSeekAware implements MessageListener<String, String> {

    @Override
    public void onMessage(ConsumerRecord<String, String> record) {
        System.out.println(ListenerUtils.recordToString(record, true));
    }

    @EventListener
    public void listen(ListenerContainerIdleEvent event) {
        System.out.println("Idle; rewinding to last");
        getSeekCallbacks().forEach((tp, callback) -> callback.seekRelative(tp.topic(), tp.partition(), -1, true));
    }

}
```

```
spring.kafka.consumer.auto-offset-reset=earliest
spring.kafka.consumer.group-id=so63957429
spring.kafka.listener.idle-event-interval=5000
```

```
so63957429-0@0
Idle; rewinding to last
2020-09-18 10:50:54.408  INFO 17195 --- [container-0-C-1] o.a.k.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer     : [Consumer clientId=consumer-so63957429-1, groupId=so63957429] Seeking to offset 0 for partition so63957429-0
so63957429-0@0
Idle; rewinding to last
2020-09-18 10:50:59.436  INFO 17195 --- [container-0-C-1] o.a.k.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer     : [Consumer clientId=consumer-so63957429-1, groupId=so63957429] Seeking to offset 0 for partition so63957429-0
so63957429-0@0
```

**EDIT**

If you need to access the last consumed record, you can add a `RecordInterceptor`:

```java
    @Bean
    public ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer<String, String> container(
            ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> factory, MyListener myListener) {

        ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer<String, String> container = factory.createContainer("so63957429");
        container.getContainerProperties().setMessageListener(myListener);
        container.setRecordInterceptor(myListener);
        return container;
    }

@Component
class MyListener extends AbstractConsumerSeekAware implements MessageListener<String, String>,
        RecordInterceptor<String, String> {

    private ConsumerRecord<String, String> lastRecord;

    @Override
    public void onMessage(ConsumerRecord<String, String> record) {
        System.out.println(ListenerUtils.recordToString(record, true));
    }

    @EventListener
    public void listen(ListenerContainerIdleEvent event) {
        System.out.println(event);
        System.out.println("Last Record: " + ListenerUtils.recordToString(this.lastRecord, true));
//      getSeekCallbacks().forEach((tp, callback) -> callback.seekRelative(tp.topic(), tp.partition(), -1, true));
    }

    @EventListener
    public void listen(ListenerContainerNoLongerIdleEvent event) {
        System.out.println(event);
    }

    @Override
    @Nullable
    public ConsumerRecord<String, String> intercept(ConsumerRecord<String, String> record) {
        return this.lastRecord = record;
    }

}
```

If you have concurrency > 1, you will need to store the last record in a `ThreadLocal`.

Comment: Thanks Gary - It definitely helped but if I may ask you a follow up question. I have a set up where I track how long the topic is idle and based on configured threshold I generate alerts. Is it possible to consume the last message in the idle event method itself ? Also I need to know when the consumption has restarted so I can reset the alert   - do you think if there is way to reset alert ? I dont want to keep resetting on the onMessage everytime . do you think its worthwhile to add a consumption restarted event  ?

Comment: In my case I really don't care about messages so would like to avoid reading them at my side  - I only care about last message before 
 the idle event occurred.

Comment: No; you can't read the last record in the event listener - in any case, you won't know which partition the last record came from. The idle event has the `idleTime` property which starts when the previous `poll()` returned some records. I added a [pull request](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/pull/1592) to publish an event when consumption resumes, but it sounds like that won't really help your use case. You could add a `RecordInterceptor` to the listener container to grab and save off the last processed record so it's available in your event listener.

Comment: See the edit to my answer to see how to capture the last consumed record.