# Spring Kafka Event Listener not seeing any Application Events

Tags: java, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I am trying to implement an event handle where some processing is done on a ListenerContainerIdleEvent. However, the container either never seems to publish the event or it's never captured. I am only interested in idle events after there has been an initial record consumed. I am able to consumer messages on the topic perfectly fine.
I have also referenced this [Use listener container for heartbeats in spring kafka](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63957429/use-listener-container-for-heartbeats-in-spring-kafka)
I have the following:

Using Spring-kafka 2.8.5

```
public AbstractConsumer(){
      
     consumerFactory = new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory(consumerConfigMap, new ErrorHandling Deserializer<>(keyDeserializer), new ErrorHandlingDeserializer<valueDeserializer>);

public void subscribe(String topic, MessageListener<K,V> listener){
    ContainerProperties properties = new ContainerProperties(topic);
    properties.setMessageListener(listener);
    properties.setGroupId(configuration.getGroupId());
    properties.setIdleEventInterval(3000L);
    ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer<K,V> container = new ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer<K,V>(consumerFactorty, properties);
    container.start()
}
```

And the MessageListener:

```
@Component
public class StatusConsumer extends AbstractConsumer implements MessageListener<K,V>{

public void setSubscribe(){
     subscribe(topic, this);

@Override
public void onMessage(ConsumerRecord){
    do stuff..
}

@EventListener
public void listen(ListenerContainerIdleEvent event){
      Log something..
}
```

I've tried implementing ApplicationListener instead of using the annotation without success. I have tried listening for other events to see if something else would get captured. Looking at the debug logs it just continually prints `KafkaMessageListenerContaiainer:Received 0 records Commit List : {}` for all scenarios. The setup seems to be correct looking at the documentaion and other examples but I am unsure what I am missing. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: By default, Kafka uses `auto.offset.reset=latest`, so will not see existing data

Comment: Sorry, I may have been unclear above, I'll edit. That is what I want I'm sure. I am trying to capture if there is an Idle event primarily after having received and processed a record from the consumer an initial time.

Comment: `new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory` 

`new ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer`

Infrastructure beans (such as the consumer and container factories) must be declared as `@Bean`s so that Spring can wire in all the plumbing necessary (such as the event publisher) for everything to work properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory`

`new ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer`

Infrastructure beans (such as the consumer and container/container factory) must be declared as `@Bean`s so that Spring can wire in all the plumbing necessary (such as the event publisher) for everything to work properly.